# substr everything after '-' and after detecting ',' in string stop and do it again, how?

Tags: php, substr

I have a string looking like this:

> earth-green, random-stuff, coffee-stuff, another-tag

I'm trying to remove everything behind the '-', but when ',' or ' ' is detected, stop and redo the process so the outgoing string becomes

> earth random coffee another

```
substr($func, 0, strrpos($func, '-'));
```

that removes everything after first '-'

Comment: your question is unclear? first one is single string or different? and also put your desired output at last and what you performed till now in middel.

Comment: use `explode` or `split` method to turn the string into an array then, in each resulted array item, you can find the position of `-` and then by using `substr` method, get your desired item. Finally, implode the array to get a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest way to do this is use the explode (convert a string into array by splitting on a character), so split on comma

http://php.net/explode

then for each of the items in that array, split on the hyphen and take the first element.

you can then glue items back together with implode (opposite of explode)

http://php.net/implode

this assumes that there are no extraneous commas or other complications

```
$str = 'earth-green, random-stuff, coffee-stuff, another-tag';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$out_arr = array();  // will put output values here

foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  $elem = trim($elem); // get rid of white space)
  $arr2 = explode('-', $elem);
  $out_arr[] = $arr2[0]; // get first element of this split, add to output array
}

echo implode(' ', $out_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach, using array_walk with an anonymous function to iterate rather than foreach.

```
<?php
$str = 'earth-green, random-stuff, coffee-stuff, another-tag';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
array_walk($arr, function( &$value, $index ) {
    $sub = explode('-', trim($value));
    $value = $sub[0];
});
var_dump($arr);
```